# How to retrieve redirect url given in window.location

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests, redirect

I am trying to make a crawler using Python. I am making use of beautifulsoup and requests library and need the set of URLs for a given website. However, in a certain part, there is redirect and when I print the response.text i.e the page content I get the following lines

```
<script>
<!--
window.location = "redirect_URL/index.php"
-->
</script>
```

How can I retrieve this url so that I crawl this url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How about regex

You just check `response.text` on redirect occurance (python):

```
regex= /window\.location\s*=\s*\"([^"]+)\"/
var occurance = regex.exec(responce.text)
if (occurance[1]) 
    print occurance[1];
```

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/qW0jR7/1).